# Convert MailItem to MSG in memory rather than filesystem

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ms-office, msg

At the moment I am base64 encoding a mailItem by writing the mailItem to an MSG file with this:

```
 mailItem.SaveAs(@"c:\path\to\save\mail.msg", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
 FileStream fs = new FileStream( fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read );
 byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
 fs.Read( filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32( fs.Length ) );
 string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String( filebytes, 
 Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks );
```

I've looked long and hard and not found a way to do this without writing the MSG to the hard drive.

Is there a way I can do this where I don't need to write to the hard drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Justin Cooney](https://jwcooney.com/2012/01/23/net-save-outlook-email-to-database-as-byte-array/) (emphasis his):

> The **Outlook.MailItem** object is in fact a **COM** object that **cannot** be dynamically saved/loaded. To achieve the desired save/load functionality the Outlook.MailItem object will **first** need to be converted to a **.MSG** file.

This is something that I would like to do as well, but alas cannot due to the limitations above. I am currently writing the file to a temp location, passing the path, converting to a Base64 string and deleting the file once successful.

Answer (score 1):

No, not using OOM. It would be possible in Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi).